# How can I produce a blinking label

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uilabel, nstimer

I want a label to be shown for 0.4 seconds and then hidden for 0.8 seconds - in an infinite loop.

How can I pull that off?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: <blink>Noooooooo!!!!!!!!!!!</blink>

Answer (score 2):

[NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) and `UIView`s [hidden](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/hidden) property would be one possibility

Comment: Your answer is good, please give some codes to support these keywords and classnames.

Comment: good questions -> good answers |

lazyly written questions -> more general, less awesome answers

Answer (score 1):

I would say to use NSTimer.  You could do it the following way:

Say your label is `myLabel`:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
```

---

You should create a method to be called by `NSTimer`:

```
- (void)changeLabelState:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    if(self.myLabel.hidden == TRUE)
    {
        self.myLabel.hidden = FALSE; //change comparassion to assing
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.4
            target:self
            selector:@selector(changeLabelState:)
            userInfo:nil
            repeats:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        self.myLabel.hidden = TRUE;
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.8
            target:self
            selector:@selector(changeLabelState:)
            userInfo:nil
            repeats:NO];
    }
}
```

---

And initialize `NSTimer` somewhere like so:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.4
    target:self
    selector:@selector(changeLabelState:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:NO];
```

---

Note that you could also do the following:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(changeLabelState:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4];

- (void)changeLabelState:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    if(self.myLabel.hidden == TRUE)
    {
        self.myLabel.hidden = FALSE;
        [self performSelector:@selector(changeLabelState:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4];
    }
    else
    {
        self.myLabel.hidden = TRUE;
        [self performSelector:@selector(changeLabelState:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.8];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something Like the below.

In viewDidLoad:

```
NSTimer *silly = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.4 target:self selector:@selector(question) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Function

```
-(void)question {

    if(label.isHidden){

      label.hidden = false;

    } else {

      label.hidden = true;

    }


}
```

Make sure you have a UILabel defined in scope of this function and it should work. UNTESTED.

Comment: if you want different time intervals you could consider passing `repeats:NO` and creating new timers inside this `question` method (if hidden -> 0.4 seconds, if not -> 0.8 seconds)